# Using loop on dictionary variable

Tags: c#

I am using dictionary variable and adding all the services name inside it and calling a foreach loop to iterate through the system and fetch all services.

I have used this code using List and it works absolutely fine, now I am using Dictionary variable and not able to loop through all the services.

```
foreach(ServiceController service in ServiceController.GetServices()) {
  string serviceName = service.ServiceName;
  string serviceDisplayName = service.DisplayName;
  string serviceType = service.ServiceType.ToString();
  string status = service.Status.ToString();

  Dictionary<int, string> output = new Dictionary<int, string>();

  if (service.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running) {
    string exists = null; {
      output.Add(1, "RUNNING SERVICE: ");
      output.Add(2, "Service Name: " + serviceName);
      output.Add(3, "Service Display Name: " + serviceDisplayName);
      output.Add(4, "Service Type: " + serviceType);
      output.Add(5, "Service Status: " + status);

      if (output.ContainsKey(1) == true) {
        exists = (output[1]);
      }
      if (output.ContainsKey(2) == true) {
        exists = (output[2]);
      }
      if (output.ContainsKey(3) == true) {
        exists = (output[3]);
      }
      if (output.ContainsKey(4) == true) {
        exists = (output[4]);
      }
      if (output.ContainsKey(5) == true) {
        exists = (output[5]);
      }

    }
  } else {}

  foreach(var i in output) {
    var result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, output);
    Result.Set(context, result);
  }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
[1, RUNNING SERVICE: ]
[2, Service Name: ZAtheros Bt and Wlan Coex Agent]
[3, Service Display Name: ZAtheros Bt and Wlan Coex Agent]
[4, Service Type: Win32OwnProcess]
[5, Service Status: Running]
```

Right now this code gives me this output. This is only one service information, I need all the services present in the system.

Comment: What is `ServiceController.GetServices().Count()`? Do you find it odd that the single entry is the **last** service running (note that it starts with a Z)? What might that tell you?

Comment: You creating your Dictionary instance inside the loop so you are end up with only last service in the dictionary (all previous service loop iterations are discarded)

Comment: Can you post the code how you are printing the result, it seems you have this context object, and you are adding all logs in some sort of map.

Comment: You are explicitly filtering out all non-running services: `if (service.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running) {...`

Comment: @TheodorZoulias The point is that the OP wants more than one record. He / she is only getting one now (the last one) due to how `Result.Set` is being called.

Comment: @mjwills I have no idea what `Result.Set()` does. I assumed that it is some kind of `Console.WriteLine`. I would say that the whole code is mind-boggling.

Comment: @Tim If I Declare dictionary instance outside the foreach and it gives me error saying 'An item with the same key has already been added'

Comment: @TheodorZoulias This is the class library code. I am using get set to print out the output.

Comment: @10five3 I doubt anyone could help you with the code you posted since it is as mentioned above "mind-boggling". Please refactor it to remove all unnecessary lines (like everything released to `exists`), check you inputs like how many items returned with `ServiceController.GetServices()` and how many of them have Status equal `ServiceControllerStatus.Running`  and maybe the solution will become obvious

Comment: @Tim This is a class library code and ServiceController.GetServices() returns all the running or stopped services and I have distinguished it as ServiceControllerStatus.Running or Stopped So .running shows only running services. My issue is i am not able to get all the services running in the system. i used to get the same using List<string> but in Dictionary<int,string> I am failing to loop it through properly.